# Substring not equal to the string of the first character

Tags: java, string, substring, equality

I am struggling to figure out what's wrong with my code. When the user input is "apple" I get that it doesn't begin with a vowel.

```java
import java.util.*;
public class StringeExerciseElearn {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type a word: ");
        String input = k.next();
        String l = input.substring(0);
        String a = "a";
        String e = "e";
        String i = "i";
        String o = "o";
        String u = "u";

        if(l.equals(a) || l.equals(e) || l.equals(i) || l.equals(o) || l.equals(u))
            System.out.println(input + " begins with a vowel!");
        else
            System.out.println(input + " doesn't begin with a vowel");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So substring willl give you a new string entirely. Check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/substring-in-java/ for more details on substring. But essentially it seems like you want to use input.charAt(0).

Comment: Please add a tag for the language you're using.

Comment: use startWith method of string instead of equals, as mentioned in previous comment substring will create new string so equal method won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake using the substring method, you should say the start position in first parameter and the end position in second parameter :

```
String l = input.substring(0, 1);
```

And now it works fine :) :

```
Type a word: 
apple
apple begins with a vowel!
```

Comment: This is misleading.  The second parameter of `substring` is not the length of the substring, it's the end index (exclusive).  When taking a substring starting at 0 they happen to be the same thing, but that wouldn't be the case otherwise.  For instance, `"apple".substring(1, 3)` returns "pp" (length 2, not length 3). Per the Javadocs: "`substring​(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`
The substring begins at the specified `beginIndex` and extends to the character at `index endIndex - 1`. Thus the length of the substring is `endIndex-beginIndex`."

Comment: yes sorry I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use startWith method of String , it will work fine.

```
public class Practice {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type a word: ");
    String input = k.next();
    String l = input;
    String a = "a";
    String e = "e";
    String i = "i";
    String o = "o";
    String u = "u";

    if (l.startsWith(a) || l.startsWith(e) || l.startsWith(i) || l.startsWith(o) || l.startsWith(u))
        System.out.println(input + " begins with a vowel!");
    else
        System.out.println(input + " doesn't begin with a vowel");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`input.substring(0)` returns the String starting at the index 0 and extending the length of the string.  In other words, it returns the input string; e.g. `"apple".substring(0)` returns "apple".

To get a single characters substring, you need to use the version of the substring method that takes both a begin index and an end index — [`public String substring​(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)):

```java
String l = input.substring(0, 1);
```

Note that this will throw an [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) for the empty string (`""`).  To prevent this, the string's length should also be checked before doing the `substring` check.